# Name for 1 minus Bernoulli variable

Tags: random-variable, terminology, bernoulli-distribution

Consider a Bernoulli variable $X$ with $\Pr[X=1]=p$, $\Pr[X=0]=1-p$. What's a commonly used name for the operation that transforms $X$ into $Y = 1-X$?

*Complement* (of $X$), *inversion* are names that come to mind, but I'm not sure what the standard one is, or which will be more easily understood in a technical paper.

To clarify: I'm aware $Y$ is also a Bernoulli variable. I'm asking about the name for the *relationship* between $X$ and $Y$, or for the *operation* that transforms $X$ into $Y$.

Comment: Why not still call it Bernoulli? After all, which event you label with 1 and which with zero typically is arbitrary.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for your comment. Of course it is a Bernoulli variable. I'm asking for a name for the _relationship_ between the two variables

Comment: So long as you define it clearly, you can call it "Bob" for all anyone (legitimately) cares.

Comment: @whuber If you have a function and compute its slope at any point, you can call that what you want, but it helps if you use the proper name _derivative_

Comment: Or you could use "differential," "slope," or "rate of change" for that matter, suggesting it might be foolhardy to seek a "standard" name for almost any mathematical operation.  The point is that as long as you know one reasonable name for some obscure or limited-scope operation, you shouldn't sweat over whether somebody else has called it something else.  The important thing is to define your operation clearly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Tim has aleady shown in his answer, if $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable, then so is $Y = 1-X$.

I would call $Y$ the "Complementary Bernoulli random variable" to $X$. I don't know that I've ever heard it called that, or anything else, but if I needed a short and sweet name, that would be it.

Edit: I guess it hasn't caught on, at least exactly as in quotes. Now, 17 months after the post, googling "Complementary Bernoulli random variable" only brings up this post. :(

Comment: Thanks. _Complement_ was my first idea too (as indicated in my question), and others agree. I'll use that

Answer (score 6):

It is *still* a Bernoulli variable, for example if $Y = 1-X$ where $X \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p)$, then

$$ Y \sim \mathrm{Bern}(1-p) $$

moreover

$$ \Bbb{1}_{Y=0} \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p) $$

where $\Bbb{1}$ is an indicator function, so it is just a matter of labeling the categories. Notice that the labeling *is* arbitrary since it is always your choice if you code "heads" as $1$, or as $0$; males, or females as $1$ etc., it doesn't matter.

If you want to name the *relationship* between the two variables, you can say that $Y$ is $X$ with *reversed* or *switched* labels, what led to Bernoulli variable with probability $1-p$.

Comment: Thanks. Of course $Y$ is also a Bernoulli variable :-) I'm asking for a name for the _relationship_ between the two variables, or equivalently the _operation_ that transforms $X$ into $Y$

Comment: @LuisMendo see my edit.